# Why is [0] a different function but 0 isn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I've inspected `.__code__` objects for two functions I deemed different, but found to be identical, for a variety of expressions. If code objects are identical, as far as I understand, they compile to same bytecode, and are thus "same" functions.

Table below is of things inserted before `; pass` that makes `g` have different `__code__`. Since `f` is a "do nothing" function, this suggests everything under "same" to *never execute*, including the long arithmetic. Further, a tuple is "same", but a list and a string are "diff" - so we might conclude that *unassigned* expressions involving *immutable literals* aren't evaluated. But then there's `1/0`, which might be an "exception" due to raising an Exception - then what of `10**99` vs. `10**9`?  `10**99` doesn't raise an Exception and can be assigned.

I couldn't tell much from profiling; both "same" and "diff" had indistinguishable execution times. When they *could* be distinguished, however, it was always with "diff".

If "same"s never execute, then how does Python determine what to or not to execute? If they do execute, how are their code objects same?

---

**Same**:

- `0`, `(0,)`, `True`, `False`, `None`
- `10 ** 9`
- `()`
- `-314159.265358 ** (1/12345) / 2.718281828 + 500 - 7j`

**Diff**:

- `[0]`, `{0: 0}`
- `10 ** 99`
- `[]`, `{}`, `""`

---

**Comparison code**:

```py
def compare(fn1, fn2):
    for name in dir(fn1.__code__):
        if (name.startswith("co_") and
            name not in ("co_filename", "co_name", "co_firstlineno")):
            v1 = getattr(fn1.__code__, name)
            v2 = getattr(fn2.__code__, name)
            if v1 == v2:
                print(name.ljust(18), "same")
            else:
                print(name.ljust(18), "diff", v1, v2)

def f():
    pass

def g():
    10 ** 99; pass
```

The following differ: `co_name` (always), `co_filename` (IPython), `co_firstlineno` (from file) - but don't affect what's "executed", correct me if wrong; from [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/datamodel.html#index-55), `co_code` is what should differ.

---

**Note**: accepted answer misses an important piece of intuition: unassigned literals code may be kept if *code required to store the value* takes more memory than *code required to store the expression to compute the value*; that's the case with `10 ** 99` (at least, that's what was asserted in the comments). See comments below the answer for further info.

Comment: What does Pypy says?

Comment: @norok2 Don't know, not using Pypy, nor can find relevant docs

Comment: The [`dis` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) will help you understand what each `co_code` value means, which will help you see which expressions are ignored and which do something

Comment: Can you please show what code you are actually running and inspecting? These are only function definitions and literals.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi They are, and that's what this question is about. I already solved my "actual problem", this is now about understanding Python (and, it can very well become a future actual problem).

Comment: Then I don't get your questions. Please clarify it. Everything in the same group, i.e. expressions that are pre-evaluated and removed, *has no observable sideeffect*. Removing it *or not* is literally meaningless for the program. Are you wondering how some specific implementation of Python arbitrarily decides what it deems worth removing? If so, which?

Comment: Note that ``""`` is removed (i.e. the "same" category) on CPython 3.7.4.final.0 and PyPy 3.6.9.final.0 (PyPy 7.3.0).

Comment: Note, by the way, these are *all* compile-time optimizations, and implementation-dependent ones at that.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm aware it's meaningless, but Python will still very much overload the entire RAM in executing `np.random.randn(1e6, 1e6)` - so _some_ expressions execute whether or not assigned; my question then is how Python decides which _not to_ execute.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon ``np.random.randn(1e6, 1e6)`` is not a literal. Python has no way of knowing whether this expression has a side-effect, including wiping the hard drive. Python *cannot* remove this, as it cannot ensure to safely evaluate it ahead of time.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Fair, bad example - though I could sit here for ages and type out a tuple that stores the same amount of information, which was more of my point (that "unassigned" != "has no effects")

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Yes, one can try different combinations all day long. Which is why it is very important that the scope of the question is clearly defined.

Comment: Voting to close as opinion-based. Any differences you see are based on arbitrary choices made by a particular implementation regarding optimizations. While there are objective thresholds you could define for when to apply an identified transformation, whether to look for such transformations in the first place is up to the implementors.

Comment: @chepner That it's "implementation based" _is_ an objective answer; I don't see what role "opinion" plays here. The answer and comments below it are based on verifiable source code that address the question being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All literals of the "diff" group are either not constants (`[]`, `{}`) or not beneficial for optimisation (e.g. `10 ** 99` is smaller than its value). All expressions of the "same" group evaluate to constants which can be discarded. Inspecting the bytecode shows that the expressions are removed completely:

```
>>> # CPython 3.7.4
>>> def g(): 10/1; pass
>>> dis.dis(g)
1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
            2 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notably, **none of the removed expressions change the observable behaviour**. Whether a Python implementation removes unobservable behaviour or not is purely an implementation detail. Expressions with side-effects, such as `1/0`, are not removed.

```
>>> # CPython 3.7.4
>>> def g(): 10/0; pass
>>> dis.dis(g)
1           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (10)
            2 LOAD_CONST               2 (0)
            4 BINARY_TRUE_DIVIDE
            6 POP_TOP
            8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           10 RETURN_VALUE
```

For the shown expressions, the bytecode is the same on CPython 3.7.4, CPython 3.8.2, PyPy 3.6.9 [PyPy 7.3.0].

On CPython 3.4.3, CPython 2.7.10, PyPy 2.7.13 [PyPy 7.1.1] the constant expression `10/1` is evaluated but not discarded.

```
>>> # CPython 3.4.3
>>> def g(): 10/1; pass
>>> dis.dis(g)
1           0 LOAD_CONST               3 (10.0)                                                                                  
            3 POP_TOP                                                                                                            
            4 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)                                                                                  
            7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The expression `""` is discarded in any Python implementation available to me.

---

As these optimisations are implementation details, there is no formal specification. If a deeper understanding is desired, the implementation itself should be consulted. For CPython, a good starting point is [the peephole optimiser source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Python/peephole.c).

> To keep the optimizer simple, it bails when the lineno table has
>   complex    encoding for gaps >= 255.
>
> Optimizations are restricted
>   to simple transformations occurring within a    single basic block. 
>   All transformations keep the code size the same or    smaller.  For
>   those that reduce size, the gaps are initially filled with    NOPs. 
>   Later those NOPs are removed and the jump addresses retargeted in    a
>   single pass.

Comment: `""` seems to be an exception to your explanation (though I think it's generally correct).

Comment: At least on the versions I have direct access to (CP 3.7.4 and PyPy3.6.9) a ``""`` is removed. Since it's an implementation detail and I do not know with which version the list in the question was made, I cannot comment on that further.

Comment: @chepner I've also tried with Python 2.7 (CPython and PyPy) which both remove ``""``.

Comment: Hm. The byte code is the same, but `g` keeps `""` as an (apparently unused) constant.

Comment: Your bolded statement is misleading; I can define an intensive computation that'll slow down a program but will be discarded immediately after; "observable" then is whether it can be profiled.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The `int` object resulting from the evaluation of `10 ** 99` would require 68 bytes of storage on a 64-bit machine (some of which is common to any object, but the value-specific storage is still well over 30 bytes); the code object that stores the function to compute it only requires 12 bytes.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Execution speed is not part of the language spec. It is observable in an implementation, just like the bytecode. It is not observable as far as language semantics are concerned.

Comment: Good example with `10/1` - this does show it to be an implementation detail. I guess the only way to understand such a detail is to inspect the version's C implementation, then?

Comment: @chepner How is code object size relevant to what it executes? Is this to say that if it's _less_ than 12 bytes then it's evaluated _before_ the function is compiled?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I've added a quote from and link to CPython's current optimiser. This addresses the criterion of folding constant expressions only when their value is smaller than the expression itself.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi This seems to be the most relevant info indeed, though I'm out of luck on reading C; to clarify, what's meant by "smaller"? Size in memory? Numeric value?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon It's relevant if the implementation decides it is not worth spending the memory to store the object instead of storing the code to compute the object.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon An expression has no numeric value. The only way to compare these is by "code size", i.e. memory size. See chepner's comment above.

Comment: It it making more sense now, though a point remains unclarified: to know the size of the object requires evaluating the expression to get "the object" - so some expressions are evaluated _before_ the function is compiled?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon The expressions are evaluated *when* the function is compiled. Evaluation is the only way to derive the value.

Comment: Alright. On the answer: chepner's comment on "memory to store the object" vs "storing the code to compute the object" is important info, and should be included. Also, the first half suggests "not constants" as a reason for being "diff", though this isn't explained, especially with what follows on "unobservable behavior" (how's an empty list any more observed than an empty tuple?) So that should either be omitted or clarified, else the answer is good to go.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Sorry, this is nothing I can work with. What do you consider needs explaining about "not constants"? ``[]`` is mutable, it is not a constant – that it happens not to be mutated does not change that. The answer includes an example of an expression that is smaller than its value, and also explicitly states that something being unobservable does not imply an *obligation* for the implementation to remove it.

Comment: So far the named rationale for discarding are: unobservable, memory, side-effects - and an empty list doesn't fit any of these (same as tuple, almost same, and none, respectively). Yes, it isn't a constant - "so what"? Is there something about mutables that cannot be "optimized away" for some reason?

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon Folding constants is guaranteed to be correct. Folding mutables requires proving they are constants which are correct to fold. No-one made the effort to make an efficient proof, and even if they had, we'd now be arguing about that one single edge case they did not manage to proof. I'm afraid "so what" is not something I can objectively answer. If you feel this warrants discussion instead of Q&A, please move this to chat.

Comment: So mutables aren't guaranteed to be correct for some reason - fine, the Q&A's scope's growing larger. Just include an explicit statement on code size vs. object size and I'll call it a day.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216094/discussion-between-mistermiyagi-and-overlordgolddragon).